# How to delete numbers, dashes and underscores in the beginning of a file name

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filenames

I have thousands of mp3 files but all with unusual file names such as  `1-2songone.mp3`, `2songtwo.mp3`, `2_2_3_songthree.mp3`. I want to remove all the numbers, dashes and underscores in the beginning of these files and get the result:

```
songone.mp3
songtwo.mp3
songthree.mp3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using extended globbing:

```
$ ls
1-2songone.mp3  2_2_3_songthree.mp3  2songtwo.mp3
$ shopt -s extglob
$ for fname in *.mp3; do mv -- "$fname" "${fname##*([-_[:digit:]])}"; done
$ ls
songone.mp3  songthree.mp3  songtwo.mp3
```

This uses [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion): `${fname##pattern}` removes the longest possible match from the beginning of `fname`. As the pattern, we use `*([-_[:digit:]])`, where `*(pattern)` stands for "zero or more matches of pattern", and the actual pattern is a bracket expression for hyhpens, underscores and digits.

**Remarks**:

- The `--` after `mv` indicates the end of options for `move` and makes sure that filenames starting with `-` aren't interpreted as options.
- The `*()` expression requires the `extglob` shell option. As pointed out, if you don't want extended globs later, you have to unset it again with `shopt -u extglob`.
- As per [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson)'s comment: this will clobber files if you have, for example, something like `1file.mp3` and `2file.mp3`. To avoid that, you can either use `mv -i` (or `--interactive`), which will prompt you before overwriting a file, or `mv -n` (or `--noclobber`), which will just not overwrite any files.
- [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) points out that this needlessly moves files onto themselves if they don't start with slash, underscore or digit. To avoid that, we can iterate only over matching files with

  ```
  for fname in [-_[:digit:]]*.mp3; do mv -- "$fname" "${fname##*([-_[:digit:]])}"; done
  ```

  which makes sure that there is something to rename.

Comment: Please always use `mv -i` for bulk moves like this, to avoid accidental data loss in case of similarly named files (or typos that make it do unexpected things, or...).

Comment: You might want to iterate over `[-_[:digit:]]*` so as to avoid needlessly moving non-matching files onto themselves.

Comment: @tripleee Good point. The question says "all with unusual filenames", but in the interest of a more generally applicable solution, I've added a remark.

Comment: Use `mv --` or `mv "./$fname"` or `for fname in ./*.mp3`, in case a filename starts with a hyphen…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Extra relevant because we're looking for files exactly like that, thanks! Updating.

Answer (score 4):

[Benjamin W.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37903478/45375) is helpful and efficient, but has two drawbacks:

- It requires setting global shell option `extglob`, which should be restored to its previous value afterward (the alternative, at the cost of creating an extra process, is to use a *subshell*: `(shopt -s extglob; for fname ...)`).
- The `extglob` syntax, an extension to regular glob syntax, is familiar to few people and still less powerful than true regular expressions.

---

Using Bash's [regex-matching operator, `=~`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

```
for f in *.mp3; do [[ $f =~ ^[0-9_-]+(.+)$ ]] && echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
```

Remove the `echo` to perform actual renaming.

- `$f =~ ^[0-9_-]+(.+)$` matches the longest nonempty sequence of digits, hyphens, and underscores at the start of the filename, followed by any nonempty sequence of characters captured in a parenthesized subexpression (capture group).
- If the match succeeds (`&&`), the `mv` command is invoked, with the captured subexpression - accessible via element `1` of special BASH array variable `${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` - forming the target filename.

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way too :

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -print0 | while read -r -d '' line
do
 mv "$line" "$( sed -E 's!(.*)/[^[:alpha:]]*([[:alpha:]].*mp3)$!\1/\2!' <<<"$line")" 2>/dev/null 
done
```

Using sed gives you more control over the regex, I guess. Also, the `2>/dev/null` is for ignoring the `mv` error for already converted/correct filenames.

---

**Note:**

This will recursively change the filenames across subfolders too.